# How to describe a scenario in gherkin retrieving an Access Token in Given clause

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

My question is much more conceptual than ever. I'd like to describe a good scenario using the Cucumber feature file where I have to have for each row of my Data table a new access token from the Identity Provider.

I.e

```
Scenario:
    Given <Code Authorization>
    And <Access Token>
    And The client has the following information
        | email  | FirstName | Phone |
        | xpto@  | Richard   | 343242|
    When the client via Post /xpto
    Then The API response a Json file
        | code | response |
        | 200  | xpto     |
```

I'll use a Data Table for this kind of approach. However, I cannot give a static Access Token because it will expire. I should get a new one every time when my test run but It is not my test it self. The Token is just a Data that I have to have to test my scenario.

Is it ok call a REST in an Given Step? If I do this I am mixing up the objective of my scenarios.

Any thougts are welcome not for your mind but by the book. :-)

Kind Regards,

Comment: In my opinion, if this is a prerequisite of the scenario I will add a Rest request for the token in Background(You could share this Background for all scenarios that need this token) rather than in Given. Even though mixing two API calls in one scenario might not be a good practice, but still better than manually update it on every run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need the token in order to set up the scenario. In that case it is fine to have that in a `Given` step. You can perform REST or other calls in step definitions for that `Given` step. For ex:  It may look something like below. You can change wordings as you like but try to word it in a manner that shows initial state of the application.

```
 Given I have a token for this scenario
 And The client has the following information 
  | email | FirstName | Phone | 
  |xpto@  | Richard   | 343242| 
 ...
 ...
```

`Given` steps are meant to establish a given state. It is considered best practice in BDD. You can find this information in official BDD docs [here](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#Given)

Also , if you want to read more about the purpose and structure of `Given` , `When` and `Then` , be sure to have a look [here](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/)